# GetIpForwardTable returns garbage on WIndows CE with PInvoke

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, windows-ce, routetable

I have a following problem. I created a PInvoke in a Windows CE .NET managed project for GetIpForwardTable function. When I call the function in returns the result, but the results are different from the result returned by the route command. There are more entries in the table, Mask and Destination changed places and NextHop is always set to 0.0.0.0

Here is the class (one needs to call IPForwardEntry.GetIpForwardTable()).

```
public class IPForwardEntry
{
    public enum ForwardType
    {
        Other = 1,
        Invalid = 2,
        Direct = 3,
        Indirect = 4
    }

    public enum ForwardProtocol
    {
        Other = 1,
        Local = 2,
        NetMGMT = 3,
        ICMP = 4,
        EGP = 5,
        GGP = 6,
        Hello = 7,
        RIP = 8,
        IS_IS = 9,
        ES_IS = 10,
        CISCO = 11,
        BBN = 12,
        OSPF = 13,
        BGP = 14,
        NT_AUTOSTATIC = 10002,
        NT_STATIC = 10006,
        NT_STATIC_NON_DOD = 10007
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MIB_IPFORWARDROW
    {
        public uint dwForwardDest;
        public uint dwForwardMask;
        public int dwForwardPolicy;
        public uint dwForwardNextHop;
        public int dwForwardIfIndex;
        public ForwardType dwForwardType;
        public ForwardProtocol dwForwardProto;
        public int dwForwardAge;
        public int dwForwardNextHopAS;
        public int dwForwardMetric1;
        public int dwForwardMetric2;
        public int dwForwardMetric3;
        public int dwForwardMetric4;
        public int dwForwardMetric5;
    }

    private IPForwardEntry(MIB_IPFORWARDROW forwardRow)
    {
        myForwardRow = forwardRow;
    }

    private MIB_IPFORWARDROW myForwardRow;

    private const int NO_ERROR = 0;

    [DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll")]
    private static extern int CreateIpForwardEntry(MIB_IPFORWARDROW[] pRoute);

    [DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll")]
    private static extern int GetIpForwardTable(MIB_IPFORWARDROW[] pIpForwardTable, ref long pdwSize, bool bOrder);

    public static IPForwardEntry[] GetIpForwardTable()
    {
        long tableSize = 0;
        GetIpForwardTable(null, ref tableSize, true);

        MIB_IPFORWARDROW[] forwardTable = new MIB_IPFORWARDROW[tableSize / Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIB_IPFORWARDROW)) + 1];

        long tableSizeOld = tableSize;

        if (GetIpForwardTable(forwardTable, ref tableSize, false) != NO_ERROR)
            throw new SystemException();

        if (tableSizeOld != tableSize)
            throw new SystemException();


        IPForwardEntry[] result = new IPForwardEntry[forwardTable.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < forwardTable.Length; i++)
            result[i] = new IPForwardEntry(forwardTable[i]);

        return result;

    }

    #region members

    public IPAddress FordwardDestination
    {
        get
        {
            return new IPAddress(myForwardRow.dwForwardDest);
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardDest = (uint) value.Address;
        }
    }

    public IPAddress ForwardMask
    {
        get
        {
            return new IPAddress(myForwardRow.dwForwardMask);
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardMask = (uint) value.Address;
        }
    }

    public int ForwardPolicy
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardPolicy;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardPolicy = value;
        }
    }

    public IPAddress ForwardNextHop
    {
        get
        {
            return new IPAddress(myForwardRow.dwForwardNextHop);
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardNextHop = (uint) value.Address;
        }
    }

    public int ForwardInterfaceIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardIfIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardIfIndex = value;
        }
    }


    public ForwardType ForwrdType
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardType;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardType = value;
        }
    }

    public ForwardProtocol Protocol
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardProto;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardProto = value;
        }
    }


    public int ForwardAge
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardAge;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardAge = value;
        }
    }

    public int ForwardNextHopAS
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardNextHopAS;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardNextHopAS = value;
        }
    }

    public int ForwardMetric1
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardMetric1;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardMetric1 = value;
        }
    }

    public int ForwardMetric2
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardMetric2;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardMetric2 = value;
        }
    }

    public int ForwardMetric3
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardMetric3;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardMetric3 = value;
        }
    }

    public int ForwardMetric4
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardMetric4;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardMetric4 = value;
        }
    }

    public int ForwardMetric5
    {
        get
        {
            return myForwardRow.dwForwardMetric5;
        }
        set
        {
            myForwardRow.dwForwardMetric5 = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetIpForwardTable doesn't return an array of MIB_IPFORWARDROW objects, it returns a MIB_IPFORWARDTABLE, that contains an array of rows *and* the number.  So that's at least one issue.  There are likely others as this is not a straightforward P/Invoke set for marshaling.

For what it's worth, I've already implemented all of this code in the [Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx), specifically in the [OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.IPRoutingTable](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/9787fc66-efdd-2b1b-1245-fbb91db2f57c.htm) class

Comment: I saw all over OpenNETCF native calls that they never use built in Marshaller to marshal complicated structures, but use byte[] arrays and then do the marshaling manually. Why is this?

Comment: For a couple of reasons.  First, a lot of the code was written back in the 1.0 days when the marshaler didn't support anything complicated and second, I trust myself more than the marshaler for complex type work (probably becasue I've been working with it since 1.0 days).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how the function works, but the following looks very suspicious.

`new MIB_IPFORWARDROW[tableSize / Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIB_IPFORWARDROW)) + 1]`

Why are you dividing by the `sizeof`?

Comment: Probably because the table contains an array of these rows (though it also contains the number, so the underlying definition is wrong, making this code invalid anyway).  These APIs are very P/Invoke unfriendly.